# Hibernate update child collection

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have a parent class 'Task' and it has child 'Tag' in it. where i want tag name(see Tag class) to be unique, but when i am trying to saving parent class a new child record is creating. How can i eliminate duplicates child records.

Here is my code

Task Class

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="tasks")
    public class TaskDTO {

    ...
    ...

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable( name = "task_tags",joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "taskId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "tagId") })
        private List<TagDTO> tags = new ArrayList<TagDTO>(); 


}
```

Tag Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tags")
public class TagDTO {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "tagId")
    private int tagId;

    @Column(name = "tagName")
    private String tagName;
}
```

TaskDAOImpl

```
@Repository("taskDAOImpl")
public class TaskDAOImpl implements TaskDAO {

@Override
    public Integer saveTask(TaskDTO taskDTO) {
        Integer identifier = null;
        try {


            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            ..........
            ..........
            identifier = (Integer) session.save(taskDTO);

            return identifier;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("unable to save task ", ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When i saved tags i get this in my database.

```
mysql> select * from tags;
+-------+---------+
| tagId | tagName |
+-------+---------+
|     1 | java    |
|     2 | java    |
+-------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from task_tags;
+--------+-------+
| taskId | tagId |
+--------+-------+
|     69 |     1 |
|     70 |     2 |
+--------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

i want to eliminate that tagName saved two times.

But i want some thing like this

```
mysql> select * from tags;
    +-------+---------+
    | tagId | tagName |
    +-------+---------+
    |     1 | java    |
    +-------+---------+
    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> select * from task_tags;
    +--------+-------+
    | taskId | tagId |
    +--------+-------+
    |     69 |     1 |
    |     70 |     1 |
    +--------+-------+
    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please help me on this. Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved this mystery like this

```
public Integer saveTask(TaskDTO taskDTO) {
        Integer identifier = null;
        try {
            ....
            ....
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            for(int i=0 ; i < taskDTO.getTags().size(); i++) {
                TagDTO tagDTO = taskDTO.getTags().get(i);
                TagDTO data = (TagDTO) session.createCriteria(TagDTO.class).add(Restrictions.eq("tagName", tagDTO.getTagName())).uniqueResult();
                if(null == data) {
                    taskDTO.getTags().set(i,tagDTO);
                } else {
                    taskDTO.getTags().set(i,data);
                }

            }
            session.beginTransaction(); // <-- this is key point, started transaction from here.
            for(int i = 0 ; i < taskDTO.getUsers().size() ; i++) {
                UserDTO userDTO = taskDTO.getUsers().get(i);
                userDTO = (UserDTO) session.get(UserDTO.class,userDTO.getUserId());
                userDTO.getTasks().add(taskDTO);
                taskDTO.getUsers().set(i,userDTO);
            }
            ....
            ....
            identifier = (Integer) session.save(taskDTO);
            return identifier;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("unable to save task ", ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I started my transaction after getting tag from db, then i see this in my database

```
mysql> select * from tags;
+-------+---------+
| tagId | tagName |
+-------+---------+
|    11 | java    |
+-------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from task_tags;
+--------+-------+
| taskId | tagId |
+--------+-------+
|     11 |    11 |
|     12 |    11 |
+--------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do one of the followings:
- either drop the setting to cascade everything on the relation, persist the tag separately and then add assign the tag to the task.
- use instead of a List a Set. It should not allow you add the same tag twice(implement an equals method on Tag to check the name)

Comment: Thanks @iullianr for your time. I tried set but is not working still i am seeing same as above.

Comment: Also tried for(int i=0 ; i < taskDTO.getTags().size(); i++) {
                TagDTO tagDTO = taskDTO.getTags().get(i);
                Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

                TagDTO data = (TagDTO) session.createCriteria(TagDTO.class).add(Restrictions.eq("tagName", tagDTO.getTagName())).uniqueResult();
                transaction.commit();
                if(null == data) {
                   session.save(tagDTO);
                   taskDTO.getTags().set(i,tagDTO);
                } else {
                    taskDTO.getTags().set(i,data);
                }

Comment: But above code is also not working, hibernate committing session on line createCriteria itself into database there by i have duplicate entries and throwing exception.Could you please help me.Thanks.

Comment: session.save should not be called before transaction.commit().

Comment: Also, why do you search for each one again? You put a unique constraint on tag name on that TAGS entity, and just save TagDTO into the database, no need to search for it.

Comment: I will get tagDTO list inside taskDTO, tagDTO will have tagname it where it comes form use.For example i have a tagname 'java', when i am saving it for first time it is ok. if i put unique constraint on tag name it is throwing duplicate tagname exception that's why i am checking tagname again.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand the flow:
1. you create a task
2. You specify some tag names for the task, but you do not select the names from a list of already existing tags you just write the names
3. You create the TagDTOs and add them to the list in TaskDTO
4. When you save TaskDTO you want, automatically, the system to determine that if a tag name already exists not to duplicate it, and also not to get an error.

In this case, you have to handle the TagDTO saving separately. So, you have your list of tags, you check to see if there are in the DB, if not, you save them and get back the persisted entity, if yes, you get the record from DB, then you add them to the list of TaskDTO and do the saving for TaskDTO. Also you need to disable the Cascading (cascade = CascadeType.ALL) in order not to force a second save (and possible errors of uniqueness).